# Using an if statement in a password manager gives me a NameError in Python

Tags: python, json

I'm building a small password manager which uses the random and string module to generate passwords at a random 15 characters long, and using the json module to store the dictionaries from the program into another file in a json format. The program is also secured with a "main" password which is also stored into the "data.json" file. On entering a wrong password, the program overwrites the old "data.json" file with a new file with the new "main" password.

Code:

```
import string
import json
import random

def generate_password():
    chars = string.ascii_lowercase + string.ascii_uppercase
    return ''.join(random.choice(chars) for i in range(15))

def get_password():
    with open('data.json', 'r') as file:
        data = json.load(file)
        return data.get('main')

print('Password manager by raphtlw\nversion 1.0')  # version info

mainPassword = input('What is your password?\n')

try:
    with open('data.json', 'r') as file:
        data = json.load(file)
        password_data = data.get('main')
except IOError:
    pass

if mainPassword == password_data: <--- <NameError>
    None
else:
    with open('data.json', 'w') as file:
        json.dump('{"main":%s}' % (mainPassword), file)
        print('Existing register overwritten! What would you like to do?')

# Main program
while True:
    print("""
    Commands:
    -----------
    1. Generate a new password
    2. Get password
    3. Quit program
    """)

    command = input('Please enter the command\n')

    if command == 1:
        label = input('Please enter a label for the password\n')
        password = generate_password()
        with open('data.json', 'a') as file:
            json.dump('{%s:%s}' % (label, password), file)
    elif command == 2:
        get_label = input('Please enter the label of the password you want to access\n')
        with open('data.json', 'r') as file:
            data = json.load(file)
            password = data.get(get_label)
        print(password)
    elif command == 3:
        quit('Program exited')
```

Error:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\raphp\Desktop\Python Projects\Password Manager\main.py", line 25, in <module>
    if mainPassword == password_data:
NameError: name 'password_data' is not defined
```

Comment: Define it outside the try block with an initial value of None. Then before checking with mainPassword, just check if it is not None

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try replacing your try block with this:

```py
password_data = None
try:
    with open('data.json', 'r') as file:
        data = json.load(file)
        password_data = data.get('main')
except IOError:
    pass

if password_data is None:
    # you had an IO error, handle it appropriately 
    pass
if main_password==password_data:
```

And then continue on with your  own code

What might be happening is that you have an IOError, which means it never hits your initialization for password_data, which is why it isn't defined...

Comment: You’re welcome! Just handle the case appropriately because otherwise your program might break later on

Answer (score 0):

Consider using encryption for the data file. The idéa of making a small portable password manager is great. But, one of the goals should also be the security aspect of it. I've also made a one-file script, maybe for inspiration. (it also has a GUI)
https://github.com/rune1979/python_simple_password_manager

Comment: post essentials, link expires in the future rendering your answer for scrap value to the bots as "low quality answer". EoR.